# How do I find the source of a constant high pitch whistle in bathroom?

Tags: bathroom, noise

I need suggestions to track down the source of a fairly loud nearly constant >1000 Hz tone which is loudest in my upstairs bathroom. I have eliminated the lights, the exhaust fan, the HVAC vent, and the water pipes as possible sources. It's not a nearby smoke detector. I have opened the attic and it is not coming from there, either. It started yesterday and it is driving me nuts.

Comment: Did you try shutting off power to your house at the main breaker?  That would rule out any AC-mains connected devices.  What about your toilet?  The fill valve can make noises like this and it can be continuous if it's leaking.

Comment: @jwh20 - yes the toilet is your main high pitch sounds - the other being a shower valve with a slight leak... think a valve that empties to tub and the tub spout hasn't emptied but shut.

Comment: @jwh20 That is exactly what is going on! The fill valve is the source. I twisted it a bit and the noise stopped. If the noise recurs, I will replace it. Thank you for your prompt insight that really helped

Comment: @phil I'm curious what steps you took to eliminate the "water pipes"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Posting as answer:

Did you try shutting off power to your house at the main breaker? That would rule out any AC-mains connected devices.

What about your toilet? The fill valve can make noises like this and it can be continuous if it's leaking.

Comment: High frequencies are quite directional. You can quickly pin down their source using an audio range oscilloscope App on your cell phone.